# samba server configuration

Tags: samba, rhel5

i m trying to configure samba server in rhel5.when i try to share some dir of my linux system on which i m configuring samba and change workgroup of one the windows clients then that windows client shows samba server icon bt on clicking that icon when i enter username and password for the registered user(means the username and password for that windows client) it does not connect to the shared dir.i changed my samba.conf file parameters several times bt even then the prob is still unsolved.what could be the other reasons for all such happenings or what shud i do with my samba.conf file.kindly help me out.

Comment: Are you trying to connect using Acitve Directory credentials?

Comment: Did you type this on your circa 1999 Nokia phone??  More people would help if your question wasn't so difficult to parse.

Answer (score 1):

If it's popping up with an auth request, try

```
smbpasswd -a <username>
```

set the password to the same as on the windows side

Answer (score 1):

Have you run testparm on your smb.conf to test for internal consistency?

Next, what sort of authentication are you using?

Try stripping out all the comments and whitespace and posting your smb.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

There's several configuration options that effect this.

`Map To Guest = [Never, Bad Password, Bad User, Bad Uid]`

The way to simulate most end-user windows machine sharing behavior is to use "Bad Password".  This means that whenever you fail to authenticate, it just uses the guest account.  Best for read-only access.

Now, under the particular share you can use the `public` option.

```
[my_share]
path = /path/to/dir
public = yes
writable = no
```

The combination of the `Map to Guest = Bad Password` configuration option, and the `public = yes` configuration option should allow anybody access your share with read-only privileges.  Be careful because smb will actually `setuid()` to the user that was authenticated (in this case, `nobody`), so all the files have to have the correct unix permissions for `nobody` to read them.

If you actually want to authenticate users, you'll have to use the `smbpasswd` tool.  Samba maintains its own shadow-hash file for users.  If you actually want to use user authentication then you'll have to use `smbpasswd -a <username>`, like greeblesnort suggests.  The username is a username of a linux user.  You can maintain different passwords for Samba authentication and for the rest of the system.  Again, you'll have to doublecheck the linux file permissions to make sure that the user you want to grant access to can read/write in the directories you're sharing.